# How can i display to the user a time elapsed when downloading?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
```

While downloading i'm starting a timer and i want to display something like:

hours minutes seconds
00:00:00

Not sure if this is nice enough to display but the idea is to display hours minutes and seconds and not like it is now that it's showing the date and time.

I just want to show the user how much time it took to download.

Comment: You need a `TimeSpan` not a `DateTime`.

Comment: You need to subtract a start time from `DateTime.Now` to get the `TimeSpan` between them.  That or use a `StopWatch`.

Comment: You also need to spawn the download on a separate thread so the UI thread doesn't get blocked.